# Interchange derivative and integral for cdf

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm considering the sum of two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, I have:
\begin{align}
Pr(X+Y \leq z) &= \int Pr(X+Y \leq z \vert Y=y)f_Y(y) dy 
\\ &= \int Pr(X \leq z-y) f_Y(y) dy
\end{align}
To find the density of $Z=X+Y$, I want to take the derivative of the above expression and put it inside the integral sign:
\begin{align}
\frac{d(Pr(Z\leq z))}{dz} = f_Z(z) = \int \frac{d}{dz}(Pr(X \leq z-y) f(y))dy
\end{align}
Can we always do that operation?

Answer (score 1):

Interchanging the order of derivative and integral is not always possible, much like two limits cannot be interchanged in general.

In this particular case, however, we can do so by the following reasoning: We know that

$$\mathbf{P}(X\leq z-y)
=\int_{-\infty}^{z-y} f_X(w)\,\mathrm{d}w
=\int_{-\infty}^{z} f_X(w-y)\,\mathrm{d}w. $$

Plugging this back,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(X+Y\leq z)
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{z}  f_X(w-y) \, \mathrm{d}w \right) f_Y(y) \,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{z} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(w-y) f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \right) \, \mathrm{d}w,
\end{align*}

where the last line follows from Fubini's theorem. Now we can invoke the following observation, which is essentially the (first part of) fundamental theorem of calculus:

> If $f$ is integrable and $ F(z) = \int_{a}^{z} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t $, then $F'(z) = f(z)$ for almost every $z$.

This gives

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\mathbf{P}(X\leq z-y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(z-y) f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y. $$

Comment: What are the hypotheses for Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @Victor, One good thing is that, if the integrand is non-negative, no extra hypothesis is required. (This particular version is often called Tonelli's theorem.)